# IBM MFP SDK for Xamarin iOS - Storing JSON with non-string property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to store a document { "id": 0, "version": 0 } into a JSONStore collection and I get a exception at AddData method.

If I change the 0 to "0", it works. The exception is thrown for any type that is 
not string (I'd like support for arrays: e.g "myArray": [1,2,3]).

Is there a workaround?
MFP 7.1.0.0

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at System.Json.JsonValue.op_Implicit (System.Json.JsonValue value) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json/JsonValue.cs:438
  at Worklight.IOSUtils.convertJSONToDictionary (System.Json.JsonObject jsonObject) [0x0006b] in :0
  at Worklight.IOSUtils.convertJSONArrayToDictionaryArray (System.Json.JsonArray arr) [0x00029] in :0
  at Worklight.Xamarin.iOS.WorklightJSONStoreCollectionIOS.AddData (System.Json.JsonArray dataArray, Worklight.WorklightJSONStoreAddOptions addOptions) [0x00002] in :0

Comment: seems like a bug. We'll verify and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in the Xamarin SDK for MobileFirst. Please open a PMR with IBM for a fix.